# Trouble running dashtools

Tags: plotly-dash

So I'm a noob when it comes to dash and python in general. I wrote an app in Dash and want to deploy it using [Dash tools](https://dash-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). However after installing using pip install dash-tools whenever I run the dashtools command I get the error 'dashtools: command not found'. Can anyone help me with this error? I am running on ubuntu.

I have tried to add it to the PATH using these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402353/how-to-add-home-username-bin-to-path). But no luck, same issue.